# Dragging browser causes background image to overlap next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a page scale or mobile compatible I think is the term. The problem with my page right now is that it looks good at a certain size but when I drag the browser, the background picture of my page covers the "Services" Title the `<section>` portion.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eg18dfy0/4/ Not sure how useful this would be as local files are not included in here.

Normal:
[image]

Dragging:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML snippet the matters:

```
<header>
  <div class="background_image">
  </div>
  <div class="welcome-text-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="welcome-text1">Welcome!</div>
      <div class="welcome-text2">BE GOOFY, TAKE A PICTURE!</div>
      <div class="btn-row">
        <a href="#services" class="welcome-btn btn-lg">TELL ME MORE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- services -->
<section id="services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="service-title">Services</div>
    <div class="service-caption">What we'll do for you</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.background_image {
    background-image: image-url("header-bg.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.64%; 
    position: absolute;
    /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
    /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}

/* Services */

#services {
    padding-top: 110px;
    margin-top: 75px;
}

.service-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.service-caption {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can include external resources using the "External Resources" tab on the left of the fiddle. There is no point creating a fiddle if it does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: or change `image-url("header-bg.jpg")` to your file's url on the server

Comment: @artm that image-url is an Ruby on Rails method. Will including the directory path to the image include the image on jsFiddle?

Comment: Updated with image!!

Comment: fiddle looks different to images here, there's a "tell me more" on fiddle but it doesn't get covered by the image, image is behind the text when you resize, not over the text.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

## [Fiddle illustrating fix](http://jsfiddle.net/eg18dfy0/5/)

You're setting your background image in a div that's getting higher stacking priority based on document flow, so it's overlapping your subsequent divs.

Here's the CSS I added to solve the problem:

```
.container > div.background-image {
    z-index: 1;
}

.container > div {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

There are better ways to do this (i.e. not creating a separate div for a background image), but this will solve your issue without major changes to document structure.

All credit to http://placehold.it for the placeholder image.  It's a life-saver if you're going to be solving CSS issues on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I fixed the issue by removing background_image in my CSS and adding this bit `header {
 background-image: image-url("header-bg.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
}`

Comment: That's another way to solve it, but don't put any clickable elements in that area then as your original `background-image` div will overlap them.